# How were 80s computer programmes so small in size?

Tags: memory-management, programming-languages, hardware

When you look at programmes written for several old computers of 80s like the commodore64 , atari and NES they are extremely small in size with most ranging to a few hundred kilobytes.

Not to mention these computers had very little memory to run on ,like Commodore 64 had 64KB of RAM and yet managed to run a GUI os!

How were these programs written to be so small?

Many of them seem to be unbelievable given the hardware constraints they had. 
On a commodore 64 its resolution of 320 x 200 @4bpp would have eaten up half its 64k mem

While Atari 2600 had just 128bytes of ram

Comment: We didnt have as much eye candy, we didnt have bloated operating systems and bloated languages.  It didnt feel small at the time it felt normal just like gigabytes feels normal today.  But someday someone will ask how could anyone survive with gigabytes and gigahertz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In today's apps, 80% or more of the on-disk size is graphical elements.
2. When space was expensive relative to programmer time,  programmers spent more time optimizing for size,  and often went to raw assembly.   Today, space is cheap, so it doesn't pay for a company to save space.
3. Compare notepad to Edlin.  Both are the simplest reasonable text editor for their paradigm. Edlin fits program and data comfortably into less than 64 K.  But there is no way one could claim notepad is a graphical Edlin.
4. C64 did not have a gui os.  It had a rudimentary menu system, and a skilled programmer could use custom hardware sprites to overlay small graphical icons.
5. In low resolution mode, you had 4 bits per pixel (16 colors).  In high resolution mode, you had 1 bit per pixel (monochrome).  Today's systems presume 16 bits per pixel or better, at 1080p (roughly 1900 x 1080 pixels).  Even monochrome displays have ballooned from 8k to we'll over 1MB.  With modern displays expecting 24 bit color depth or better,  the minimum storage required for a single frame is multi megabytes. Add to that the working space for buffering and other things that a modern graphics card does, and it doesn't take long for your graphics needs to run To gigabytes. There is a reason the high resolution mode on that generation of computer was rarely used.
6. When you loaded a program,  you unloaded the os.  You ran only one program at time.  Today I regularly run twenty or more apps at a time, not to mention dozens of background processes necessary to do my work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for other systems, but for the C64 (and C128)...

As @pojo-guy stated, we often went straight to assembly, which cut down on operating system overhead, since the OS was in ROM, so it used no RAM.  Moreover, you could flip ROM in and out by playing with the memory registers, virtually "doubling" the available memory (although some of that "available" memory was read-only, the key point being that you didn't waste precious RAM on OS routines).  By utilizing ROM routines, and using straight assembly, a large amount of (memory) overhead was eliminated.

For bitmaps you had two choices: high resolution, or multi-colour mode.  In high resolution (320 x 200), each pixel showed either the foreground, or background, colour - so you only needed 320 x 200 = 64,000 bits or 8000 bytes.

Standard multi-colour mode offered four colours at the expense of horizontal resolution.  To quote the C64 programmers reference manual:

> Each dot in multi-colour mode can be one of 4 colours: screen colour (background colour register #0), the colour in background colour register #1, the colour in background colour register #2, or character colour.  The only sacrifice is the horizontal resolution, because each multi-colour mode dot is twice as wide a a high-resolution dot.  The minimal resolution is more than compensated for by the extra capabilities of multi-colour mode.

The reduction in overhead, a simpler OS (which could be completely swapped out), and simpler functionality (e.g. 2-bit colour which allowed you to have four colours), made things much smaller.  As techniques improved, coders also applied overlays: loading parts in while other parts were playing.

Also, more advanced architectures (e.g. C128) had separate video RAM (either 16K or 64K depending on your model of C128), which gave even more space to flex your coding muscles, since graphics (or text) did not take up processing space.

Look up any of the 4k demo competitions to see what can really be done a machine with such a small memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

As C64 is 8-bit computer, all assembly language commands are 8 bits long. In addition to that, they might have 0-2 data bytes after it. So each command takes 1-3 bytes of ram.

Now when we move forward to more modern systems, the CPU is already often 64bit.

Basically, all CPU's have some "preferred sizes" for variables (which it can handle efficiently), and usually, it's exactly same number as how many "bits" does your processor have. This is usually what "int" is in C (with the exception, that it's guaranteed to always be at least 16bit, while obviously the "preferred" size on 8-bit CPUs is 8 bits)

So for an integer, no matter how small it might be, it's most efficient to use this "preferred size".
So on 8-bit systems, that would be 8 bits (obviously can't be int), and on 64bit systems, that would be 64 bits. So that's 8x in size.

Of course you can use smaller types, but often it's less efficient, and often, this also affects struct padding too.

But with pointers, you're often stuck with the amount of bits the CPU has (as you need to be able to address the whole memory range)

And while data values are generally bigger, so are assembly language commands. On the other hand, that allows for more complex commands, which can perform operations, that would need more 8-bit commands.

Of course there are exceptions, like thumb command set on ARM.

What I am saying is, efficient assembly language code on a modern platform takes more space than C64 assembly language (but is less restricted, and can do fancy stuff, such as multiply / divide etc.)

As for graphical operating systems on C64, the 2 best known ones are [GEOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEOS_(8-bit_operating_system)) and [Contiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiki). Final Cartridge 3 also had a built in windowing system, but iirc, only allowed built-in programs, and there wasn't anything that useful.

GEOS is rather "restricted", doesn't do any real multitasking (you can select which program is displayed in the main area of the window, but f.ex. clock is always running), and that's basically it. And even if it is restricted, there is f.ex. rather nice word processor (GEOWrite) for it, which I used back in the day.

Contiki is more "modern" (and actually mostly written in C iirc), and it's actually much more simple than you might think. It runs in character gfx mode (so 1000 bytes for onscreen graphics 0 2k for charset, and 1k color ram), so that's only 4k wasted there.

And I'd say Contiki is more of "proof of concept" than actually useful operating system, but unlike GEOS, does real (co-operative) multitasking.

I guess you're seriously overestimating what would be needed for a really simple graphical operating system. Instead, you could compare to [AmigaOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaOS), which was very modern for its time, and still rather small, and runs on CPU that's (internally) 32bit, so much closer to modern processors.